# Error API conekta invalid_datatype

Tags: array, json, api, curl

les comparto el siguiente problema.

Cuando intento crear un pago recurrente a través de SPEI recibo el siguiente error:

```
{
    "details": [
        {
            "debug_message": "Invalid datatype for \"payment_sources\" expecting at least normal Array.",
            "message": "\"payment_sources\" tiene un tipo inválido.",
            "param": "payment_sources",
            "code": "conekta.errors.parameter_validation.payment_sources.invalid_datatype"
        }
    ],
    "object": "error",
    "type": "parameter_validation_error",
    "log_id": "63a156b38222ff0015fd5164"
}
```

Sin embargo por más que he verificado en apariencia la solicitud esta como lo solicita la documentación, la solicitud es esta:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.conekta.io/customers' \
--header 'accept: application/vnd.conekta-v2.0.0+json' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "Arturo Alb",
    "email": "pagos@dominio.com",
    "phone": "+525555555555",
    "payment_sources": {
        "type": "spei_recurrent"
    }
}'
```

Espero alguien me pueda hechar algo de luz al respecto.

Comment: Probaste agregar el tipo array ahi? asi entonces en "payment_sources", lo cambias por "payment_sources" : [{ "type": "spei_recurrent" }]

Comment: @AugustoM jajajaja no puedo creer que era algo tan sencillo, si ya me dejo, me devuelve los valores correctos, muchas gracias bro, si quieres ponlo como respuesta para colocarte como solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el mensaje de error que recibes tienes que cambiar tu payload a un tipo de array:

Entonces te quedaria:

```json
{
    "name": "Arturo Alb",
    "email": "pagos@dominio.com",
    "phone": "+525555555555",
    "payment_sources": [{
        "type": "spei_recurrent"
    }]
}
```